# Phonegap app is killed on pressing back button on Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, cordova, ondestroy

I have a phonegap based app using phonegap 2.1
I have added handling of back button.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // Move the application to background on back button press.

    if (!moveTaskToBack(false)) {

        Log.e("myApp", "Failed to move the app to background");

    }

    return;

}
```

Now on Samsung Tab with Android 4.1.1 the app gets killed when back or home button is pressed.
However the same code works on Nexus device having Android 4.2.2

Here is the log cat

```
09-19 18:43:01.463: D/DroidGap(27265): onMessage(spinner,stop)
09-19 18:43:02.752: D/CordovaWebView(27265): >>> loadUrlNow()
09-19 18:43:02.760: D/WebView(27265): loadUrlImpl: called
09-19 18:43:02.760: D/webcore(27265):  CORE loadUrl: called
09-19 18:43:02.767: D/webkit(27265): Firewall not null
09-19 18:43:02.767: D/webkit(27265): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
09-19 18:43:02.838: D/DroidGap(27265): Paused the application!
09-19 18:43:02.838: D/CordovaWebView(27265): Handle the pause
09-19 18:43:02.838: D/CordovaWebView(27265): >>> loadUrlNow()
09-19 18:43:02.838: D/WebView(27265): loadUrlImpl: called
09-19 18:43:02.877: D/webcore(27265):  CORE loadUrl: called
09-19 18:43:02.877: D/webkit(27265): Firewall not null
09-19 18:43:02.877: D/webkit(27265): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
09-19 18:43:03.853: D/DroidGap(27265): onDestroy()
09-19 18:43:03.853: D/CordovaWebView(27265): >>> loadUrlNow()
09-19 18:43:03.861: D/WebView(27265): loadUrlImpl: called
09-19 18:43:03.861: D/webcore(27265):  CORE loadUrl: called
09-19 18:43:03.861: D/webkit(27265): Firewall not null
09-19 18:43:03.861: D/CordovaWebView(27265): >>> loadUrlNow()
09-19 18:43:03.869: D/webkit(27265): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
09-19 18:43:03.869: D/WebView(27265): loadUrlImpl: called
09-19 18:43:03.869: D/webcore(27265):  CORE loadUrl: called
09-19 18:43:03.869: D/webkit(27265): Firewall not null
09-19 18:43:03.869: D/webkit(27265): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
```